# how do you monitor your lamp server?

Tags: linux, monitoring, lamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Apache Server Performance Monitoring](https://serverfault.com/questions/103964/apache-server-performance-monitoring)

i wonder how one can monitor a lamp server (ubuntu) on production.

are there any standard tools for this to watch the server performance/load in realtime via the browser? how mysql, linux, apache etc are doing...

what is best practice regarding this?

any tutorials would be great. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look at Nagios:

http://www.hyperic.com/products/nagios-monitoring

It's open source, supports monitoring of pretty much anything you can think of. The last place I was at used it for the entire enterprise (web servers, database, network, applications, etc)

Answer (score 0):

http://munin-monitoring.org/ is another option